# Groups of order 494

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I need to find three non abelian, non isomorphic groups of order 494.

I have already found two the most trivial: $D_{247}$ and $D_{13}\times \mathbb Z/19\mathbb Z$ but I need one more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$D_{19}\times \mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, silly me :) I thought I was looking at $C_{19}\times \mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z$ but of course that's abelian and a pretty silly way to mix two notations. Sorry for the noise